# Manual delete/add of rows in DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've been trying to figure this out since yesterday and nothing I've tried is working.

I have a table that uses DataTables (datatables.net). It has a requirement of being programmatically cleared of all rows and then new rows being added depending on user input data in other form fields. The page uses Ajax to acquire new data for the table, but the data requires customizations so I cannot use the returned JSON directly.

Initially, the page loads with this HTML for the `<table>`:

```
<table id="outputtable" class="stripe hover compact order-column">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center"></th>
            <th class="text-center"></th>
            <th class="text-center"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    oTable = null;      // Output table

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        oTable = $('#outputtable').DataTable({
            dom: "t",
            "scrollY": "250px",
            "scrollX": false,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false
        });
    });

</script>
```

Elsewhere on the page I have some buttons that have events wired. For example:

```
$('#btnRate').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault;

    oTable.fnClearTable();

    oTable.row.add([{
        "name": "Tiger Nixon",
        "position": "System Architect",
        "salary": "$3,120"
    }, {
        "name": "Garrett Winters",
        "position": "Director",
        "salary": "$5,300"
    }])
    .draw();

    return false;
})
```

Since `oTable` is global and initialized in `(document).ready()` it should be available throughout my jQuery. For some reason I am not able to delete all existing rows or add new ones. After clicking the `#btnRate` button the click event fires, each line of code executes, but no change is made to the `outputtable` and no error is thrown.

The above data is just an example I've been trying to get working. I'll deal with real data once I get the example to work. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.To add more than 1 row at once you need to use `rows.add()` not `row.add()`

2.`fnClearTable` is no longer a function of datatables. See [1.10-convert](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert)

3.Your table isn't setup to use object data, so don't pass in objects, pass in arrays.

```
oTable.rows.add([
    ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "$3,120"],
    ["Garrett Winters", "Director", "$5,300"],
]).draw();
```

Comment: I tried both rows.add and row.add. The latter didn't seem right to me, but it is exactly what the example shows on datatables.net. I will try your suggestions a little later tonight. Thank you!

Comment: yeah i noticed the rows.add() in the docs example has a typo, it says row.add, but should be rows.add

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the initialization returns a reference to the Datatable.
[Datatables Manual](http://www.datatables.net/manual/index)

But why not use the selector to get a refference to the JQuery object?

See "[Accessing the API](http://www.datatables.net/manual/api)" here

```
$( '#outputtable' ).DataTable();
```

or

```
$( '#outputtable' ).dataTable().api();
```

or

```
new $.fn.dataTable.Api( '#outputtable' );
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jcarte16/tocmypy3/30/) is a jsfiddle example I did.

Comment: Is your jsfiddle link correct? I'm not sure how it applies. ;)

Comment: So should be able to get a reference to the DataTable() with the suggestions above, but I'm still not getting the new rows added to the table :(

Comment: I tried modifying your jsfiddle also but can't get rows to add. I see examples all over the place and on datatables.net as well, but none of them are working for me either.

Answer (score 0):

To delete all existing rows in data table you can use

```
oTable.clear();
```

and To add new rows

```
oTable.rows.add(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
                ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
);
```

and to  reflect changes use

```
oTable.draw();
```